# StructureMap specific constructor - how should parameters be initialized?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, structuremap

Given the following piece of a StructureMap registry

```
For<ILogger>().Use(LogFactory.CreateLogger());
For<Scheduler>().Use(() => new Scheduler(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ILogger>()));
```

...is this a **good** way of providing an `ILogger` to the `Scheduler`? It *works* - but I'm curious to know if it's a poor way of providing a type that the container is configured to provide, or whether it's my only option given the scenario... the scenario being that the `Scheduler` type itself has other constructors which I cannot change, nor do I care for - but they are needed, so I need to specify this particular constructor rather than using a straight `For<x>().Use<y>();`

Comment: `For<Scheduler>().Use(c => new Scheduler(c.GetInstance<ILogger>()));` - use the overload the provides the container's build context, instead of ObjectFactory.

Comment: @JoshuaFlanagan +1, Excellent - thanks for that, makes it look a lot nicer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best if the registered service has exactly one public constructor. This makes it unambiguous what dependencies a service makes and makes it very clear which constructor will be selected by the container, and it allows you to register types using the more flexible `Use<T>()`, and makes the composition root less likely to be changed when the constructor changed.

However, as you said, in your case you can't change the constructors of that type, so you will have to fall back. There are multiple ways to select the proper constructor with StructureMap, but registering a delegate is the best way, since this gives you compile time support.

Comment: Thanks for that - so in essence, what I have is "as much as I can do" given the circumstance. I would certainly much prefer to have single ctor types and for the most part, I do.